# Python 3 - classes and private objects

Tags: python, class, object

I'm new to python and don't know why this code wont run. I'm trying to make an employee class and access it and initialise an object from a different class here's the class code:

```
class employee:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__name
        self.__num


    def employee(self):
        self.__name = "Brian"
        self.__num = 40000

    def employee(self, n ,x):
        self.__name = n
        self.__num = x

    def setName(self, n):
        self.__name = n

    def getName(self):
        return self.__name

    def setNum(self, x):
        self.__num = x

    def getNum(self):
        return self.__num

    def toString(self):
        res = "Name: " + self.__name
        res += "\nNum: " + self.__num
```

and here's the test code:

```
import Employee
def main():

    jane = Employee.employee("Jane", 40000)
    brian = Employee.employee()

    print(brian.toString())
    print(jane.toString())

main()
```

Comment: You're calling object methods as if they were class methods. Move all the initialising logic into the constructor.

Comment: 1. Fix the indentation. 2. What do you expect `self.__name` in `__init__` to do? 3. The usage of Getters and Setters (as you implemented it) is quite uncommon in Python. 4. The second definition of the `employee` method overwrites the first. 5. The whole code looks like you're trying to write Java in Python.

Comment: this is not the way to go in Python. Have a look at the [classes documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)

Answer (score 1):

First read this : https://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html

and then this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Then rewrite your code the Python way:

```
# employee.py (module names should be all lower)    
class Employee(object):
    # inheriting from `object` is only useful in python2
    # but doesn't break anything in python3

    def __init__(self, name="Brian", num=4000):
        self.name = name
        self.num = num

    def __str__(self):
        # this will be automagically called when trying
        # to make a string out of an Employee
        return "Name: {self.name}\nNum: {self.num}".format(self=self)

    # and that's all. You don't need private attributes nor
    # accessors, Python has a strong support for computed 
    # attributes so you can turn plain attributes into
    # computed ones later if needed (without breaking
    # the client code of course).
```

and the test code

```
# test.py
from employee import Employee

def main():
    # instanciating a class is done by calling it
    jane = Employee("Jane", 40000)
    brian = Employee()

    print(jane)
    print(brian)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I strongly suggest you at least follow the full Python tutorial before trying to write PHP or Java code in Python, it'll save everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

You class definition does not look good to me.

In the **init** method you don't assign anything to the attributes. It should be like:

```
class employee:

    def __init__(self, name, num):
        self.name = name
        self.num = num
```

Furthermore your second instantiation is missing the attributes. Should be like:

```
brian = Employee.employee("Brian", 30.000)
```

Your ToString method is also incorrect, you cannot concatenate strings like that. Try something like:

```
def toString(self):
    res = "Name: {}, Num: {}".format(self.name, self.num)
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

you are writing python in java style. See [classes documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)

```
class Employee:

    # initialize constructor with default arguments
    def __init__(self, name="Brian", num=40000):
        self.name = name
        self.num = num

    # you don't need this. this is the work of "__init__" function above
    def employee(self, n ,x):
        self.__name = n
        self.__num = x

    def set_name(self, n):
        self.name = n

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def set_num(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def get_num(self):
        return self.num

    # tostring equivalent
    def __str__(self):
        # string format
        return "Name: {0}\nNum: {1}".format(self.name, self.num)
```

Testing the code

```
def main():
    # you don't need to import employee class if in the same file
    import Employee

    # creating instances
    jane = Employee("Jane", 40000)
    brian = Employee()

    print(brian)
    print(jane)


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

will print out

```
>>> Name: Brian
>>> Num: 40000
>>> Name: Jane
>>> Num: 40000
```